# Datatables Offset.top and scrollTop set to zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, bootstrap-modal

I have a datatables table with infinite scrolling and no paging.  When the user clicks a row, I insert a child row with details, and scroll the clicked row to the top.

This is all working perfectly.

However, I have a button on the child row that shows a bootstrap modal.
When the user dismisses the modal, the offset() and scrolltop() values for the dataTables_scrollBody are set to zero.
This causes the datatable to scroll incorrectly.

So I saved the values before showing the modal.  Then after the model is hidden, I attempted to set the offset and scrolltop to the saved values.
I get no error, but the values stay zero.

Here is the code I am using to scroll the grid:

```
var container = $('#MainContent_grdBrowse,div.dataTables_scrollBody');
var scrollTo = $('.shown'); 
container.animate({
    scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
});
```

Here is the code to restore the values:

```
container.offset({ top: dt_OffSetTop, left: dt_OffSetLeft });
container.scrollTop(dt_Scrolltop);
```

I get the same results in Firefox & IE.

Edit:
Here is the code where I save, and restore the values.

I save the values to hidden fields in the datatables click event:

```
document.getElementById('MainContent_dt_OffSetTop').value = container.offset().top;
document.getElementById('MainContent_dt_OffSetLeft').value = container.offset().left;
document.getElementById('MainContent_dt_Scrolltop').value = container.scrollTop();
document.getElementById('MainContent_rw_OffSetTop').value = scrollTo.offset().top;
document.getElementById('MainContent_rw_OffSetleft').value = scrollTo.offset().left;
```

I restore the values in the hidden.bs.modal event:

```
$('#ModalDisplayNotes').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var dt_OffSetTop = document.getElementById('MainContent_dt_OffSetTop').value;
    var dt_OffSetLeft = document.getElementById('MainContent_dt_OffSetLeft').value;
    var dt_Scrolltop = document.getElementById('MainContent_dt_Scrolltop').value;
    var rw_OffSetTop = document.getElementById('MainContent_rw_OffSetTop').value;
    var rw_OffSetleft = document.getElementById('MainContent_rw_OffSetleft').value;
    var container = $('#MainContent_grdBrowse,div.dataTables_scrollBody');
    var scrollTo = $('.shown');
    container.offset({ top: dt_OffSetTop, left: dt_OffSetLeft });
    container.scrollTop(dt_Scrolltop);
    scrollTo.offset({ top: rw_OffSetTop, left: rw_OffSetleft });
})
```

I displayed the values when I saved them and they were correct.  I displayed the values returned from the hidden fields in the hidden-bs-modal event, and they were correct.  Then I set the values to the datatable body.  Then when I query the values from the datatables body, they are zero.

Comment: Can you post the part where you store the values? Also the context where you restore them, not just that lines.

Comment: I added the code above.